# merge two or more simulations

Tags: r, merge, simulation

I`m simulating the wind power with weibull distribution for every week and every month in year. Because there are weekly differences in wind speed/power I want to combine them all and then replicate the result to see how much energy the particular wind location can produce in certain time. The first simulation produces results for the first week the second simulation for the second week and so on, with the goal having the merged results for one month and then replicate the results for desired number of months.

```
first<-rweibull(7,3.28,2.14) #time series for days in first week
second<-rweibull(7,3.33,2.112)# time series for days in second week 
combined<-replicate(2,c(first,second))#combined

     [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 2.3314627 2.3314627
 [2,] 2.4219863 2.4219863
 [3,] 2.2993156 2.2993156
 [4,] 0.9576821 0.9576821
 [5,] 0.8065639 0.8065639
 [6,] 2.2820711 2.2820711
 [7,] 0.6315118 0.6315118
 [8,] 1.8152144 1.8152144
 [9,] 0.9296449 0.9296449
[10,] 1.6707807 1.6707807
[11,] 1.7307920 1.7307920
[12,] 2.2075004 2.2075004
[13,] 2.0368642 2.0368642
[14,] 2.5320678 2.5320678
```

Now the problem is that when I replicate I get the same result but the results should be different. Is there any simple and fast solution for that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? what is the expected output like? I don't see you are passing any function to replicate , its confusing when you said combined and using replicate...`cbind` should combine as well

Comment: I`m simulating the wind power with weibull distribution for every week and every month in year. Because there are weekly differences in wind speed/power I want to combine them all and then replicate the result to see how  much energy the particular wind location can produce in certain time

Comment: or you should pass it something like this `replicate(2, c(rweibull(7,3.28,2.14),rweibull(7,3.33,2.112)) ) `. rather than storing in a variable adn pass it later

Comment: It is a practical solution but I was looking for something more elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing variables to `replicate` you can do this.

**code**

```
fun <- function( ){
  first  <- rweibull(7,3.28,2.14) 
  second <- rweibull(7,3.33,2.112) 
}

replicate( 2, fun() )
```